# Orchard 1.7 - Feature Itemslider

Tags: orchardcms-1.7

I created a new Orchard 1.7 site with only the Feature Item Slider module installed. I can create a new feature, however I do not get the picture field and none of the feature are displayed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. 
Install "Media Picker" module by The Orchard Team from gallery then enable it 
It works fine with my Orchard 1.7.2

Comment: The `Media Picker` and it's dependant `Media` feature have both been deprecated as far as I'm aware

Comment: Are they both replaced by `Media Library`?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used FeaturedItemSlider module in 1.7 but I do know it uses the media picker field and this is no longer used in 1.7. I would guess this is the problem. So either try using 1.6 or have a look at other alternatives to the Featured Item Slider module.

eg. http://www.breakoutdeveloper.com/orchard/content-item-slider

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, I just fixed it today. Quick steps for the dirty fix below:

1. Add reference to Orchard.MediaLibrary for FeaturedItemSlider
   (remember to also add the dependency in Module.txt)
2. Go into and update **FeaturedItemSliderWidgetPartDriver.cs**
3. Add reference through **using Orchard.MediaLibrary.Fields;**
4. Add this function (may be offloaded onto a Service Class but I'm in a hurry so just added to the driver, sorry):

   ```
       //new function for 1.7
       protected string getImagePath(FeaturedItemPart part) {

           if (((MediaLibraryPickerField)part.Fields.Single(f => f.Name == "Picture")).MediaParts.Any())
           {
               return ((MediaLibraryPickerField)part.Fields.Single(f => f.Name == "Picture")).MediaParts.FirstOrDefault().MediaUrl;
           }

           return string.Empty;
       }
   ```
5. Updated **featuredItems** variable in the Display function:

   ```
           var featuredItems = _contentManager.Query<FeaturedItemPart, FeaturedItemPartRecord>("FeaturedItem")
               .Where(fip => fip.GroupName == part.GroupName)
               .OrderBy(fi => fi.SlideOrder)
               .List()
               .Select(fi => new FeaturedItemViewModel
               {
                   Headline = fi.Headline,
                   SubHeadline = fi.SubHeadline,
                   LinkUrl = fi.LinkUrl,
                   SeparateLink = fi.SeparateLink,
                   LinkText = fi.LinkText,
                   //updated due to 1.7.2 upgrade, MediaPicker -> MediaLibraryPicker
                   ImagePath = getImagePath(fi),
                   SlideNumber = ++slideNumber
               }).ToList();
   ```

That should do it. To explain, MediaPicker was replaced with MediaLibraryPicker and now Media are treated as Content Items, so properties have changed. Details of media are now in a MediaPart within the Media Content Item.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded a site from Orchard 1.6 to 1.7.2, and had some success by taking the following steps:

Because I had migrated from 1.6, I already had `Media Picker` and `Media` features enabled. I then also enabled then three new media features- `Media Library`, `Media Library Search` and `Media Processing`. I also enabled the `Upgrade` feature

I then clicked `Upgrade to 1.7` on the admin menu and migrated my media files.

After that finished, I migrated the media picker fields. This moves all of your old `Media Picker` fields to the newer `Media Library Picker` fields.

When that is complete, you can disable the features `Media Picker` and `Media`

Answer (score 0):

Sunkist on GitHub created a patched version of the Featured Item Slider which seems to be working perfectly fine: https://github.com/sunkist/FeaturedItemSlider.

I don't know if it will be maintained but it works ok now.